# Need a htaccess redirect rule to ignore a certain folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm redirecting my .com website to .net using this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cartoonizemypet\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.cartoonizemypet\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.cartoonizemypet\.net\/$1" [R=302,L]
```

Which works (huzzah!)  The problem is I need to also exclude a single folder and all of it's contents: http://www.cartoonizemypet.com/catoonizer

I've been messing around with it all day, trying to adapt other peoples from here, but I just keep breaking the site.  I'm afraid I just don't know that much about rewrite rules.

Does anyone know how I can make it work?

Comment: Your rule should redirect `http://www.cartoonizemypet.com/catoonizer` to `http://www.cartoonizemypet.net/catoonizer`

Comment: I want the rules I have, so .com directs to .net

Comment: but I need the catoonizer folder to stay on .com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/catoonizer
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cartoonizemypet\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.cartoonizemypet\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.cartoonizemypet\.net\/$1" [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Yesss!  It works!! :)  One thing though, how would I also get http://cartoonizemypet.com/catoonizer (without the www) to not redirect to .net

Comment: @user1597021 This ignores that directory for both. Make sure you've cleared your browser's cache.

Comment: Awww smeg... for some reason the version without the www loads, but you can't export the cats.  Is there a way I can force the version without the www to go to the one with it?

Comment: It's OK, found the answer! :D  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
# Turn the engine on if it's not already
RewriteEngine On
# Check to make sure we're on the right host (www is optional)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?cartoonizemypet\.com$ [NC]
# Check to make sure we're not at the catoonizer URI (I assume that's a misspelling
# but it's what was in the example).
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/catoonizer) [NC]
# If all conditions are met, redirect as 302.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cartoonizemypet.net/$1 [R=302,L]
```